# MySql subquery: average difference, grouped by column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

I have a mysql table with visitor_id, country, time_of_visit.

I want to get the average duration of visit by country.

To get duration, I get the difference between the earliest and latest time_of_visit for each visitor_id.

So this gets me the average duration of all visits:

```
    SELECT AVG(duration)
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(time_of_visit), MAX(time_of_visit))/60 
as duration 
    FROM tracker 
    GROUP BY visitor_id
    ) as tracker
```

That works. But to group it by country, I fail. Here's my most recent attempt to get average duration by country:

```
SELECT country, AVG(duration)
FROM 
(
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(time_of_visit), MAX(time_of_visit))/60 
as duration 
FROM tracker 
GROUP BY visitor_id
) as tracker
GROUP BY country
```

The error I get is: Unknown column 'country' in 'field list'.

I think this should be simple, but I'm a noob. I searched a lot, tried lots of ideas, but no good. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select the country column in your subquery and then have to reference the country field from the derived table  `tracker.country`

```
SELECT tracker.country, AVG(tracker.duration)
FROM 
(
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(time_of_visit), MAX(time_of_visit))/60     
as duration ,country
FROM tracker 
GROUP BY visitor_id
) as tracker
GROUP BY tracker.country
```

**Edit**

> Using `GROUP BY` in subselect `visitor_id` will gives you the record
>   with duplicate data for countries and when using `GROUP BY` with both
>   `visitor_id,country` will group the data of countries within the same
>   visitor id, this will only possible if one visitor will belong to more
>   than one countries , if one visitor will belong to only one country
>   i.e one-to-one  relation then just use `GROUP BY visitor_id`

Comment: Your solution works great, thanks. Should the inner GROUP BY have both visitor_id, country... or just visitor_id? One solution has both, one solution has only visitor_id. They both work, but I really don't know if it makes a difference, and which is better to use or why?

Comment: Thanks for the change and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the column in the subquery which you want to show it in the outer query
Try this::

```
SELECT country, AVG(duration)
FROM 
(
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(time_of_visit), MAX(time_of_visit))/60 
as duration, country 
FROM tracker 
GROUP BY visitor_id
) as tracker
GROUP BY country
```

You can also try:

```
SELECT 
country, 
AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(time_of_visit), MAX(time_of_visit))/60) as avgTime
FROM 
GROUP BY visitor_id,country
```

Comment: Thanks. The first code works. The second one returns error "invalid use of group function".

Answer (score 0):

You should add COUNTRY to the inner GROUP BY and a field list

```
SELECT country, AVG(duration)
FROM 
(
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(time_of_visit), MAX(time_of_visit))/60 
as duration,country,visitor_id 
FROM tracker 
GROUP BY visitor_id,country
) as tracker
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is it better to GROUP BY visitor_id,, country on the inner GROUP BY as in this solution, or better to SELECT duration, country on the inside and only GROUP BY visitor_id as in the other solutions? They both work, I just don't which is better or why... Thanks.